# How do you make unique_ptrs with the these initializations?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

What are the equivalent versions of making `std::unique_ptr` using `std::make_unique` with the following initializations?

```
// Single object
// 1: Indeterminate value
new int; 
// 2: Zero initialized
new int();
// 3: Initialized with 7
new int(7);

    
// Arrays
// 1: Indeterminate values
new int[10];
// 2: All zero-initialized
new int[10]();
// 3: Initialized with list, (rest all zero)
new int[10]{ 7, 6, 5, 4 };
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<int> p{ new ... };`  / `std::unique_ptr<int[]> p{ new int[10]... }` ? Not sure if I understand the question

Comment: `std::make_unique_for_overwrite` is what you mean by indeterminate values, but it's only available since C++20.

Comment: Yes, using make_unique, I've added to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counter parts are:

```
// Single object
// 1: Indeterminate value
new int;
std::make_unique_for_overwrite<int>(); // since C++20

// 2: Zero initialized
new int();
std::make_unique<int>();

// 3: Initialized with 7
new int(7);
std::make_unique<int>(7);
```

```
// Arrays
// 1: Indeterminate values
new int[10];
std::make_unique_for_overwrite<int[]>(10); // Since C++20
// 2: All zero-initialized
new int[10]();
std::make_unique<int[]>(10);
// 3: Initialized with list, (rest all zero).
new int[10]{ 7, 6, 5, 4 };
std::unique_ptr<int[]>{ new int[10]{ 7, 6, 5, 4 } };
```

[`std::make_unique_for_overwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) is C++20 only.